# How to create a limited number of threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm beginner in threads and I have one question.
I have a vector with all .txt files in the current directory. How to count them in a given number of threads (by default - 4 threads).
I heard about ThreadPool and found this code:

ThreadPool.h

```
#ifndef THREAD_POOL_H
#define THREAD_POOL_H

#include <vector>
#include <queue>
#include <memory>
#include <functional>
#include <stdexcept>

#include <vector>
#include <queue>

#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/mutex.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/condition_variable.hpp>
#include <future> // boost future is not working for me 

class ThreadPool
{
public:
    using Task = std::function<void()>;

    explicit ThreadPool(std::size_t threads_count);
    ~ThreadPool();
    template <class T>
    auto enqueue(T task) -> std::future<decltype(task())>
    {
        auto wrapper = std::make_shared<std::packaged_task<decltype(task()) ()>>(std::move(task));
        {
            boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(mutex_p);
            tasks_p.emplace([=] {
                (*wrapper)();
            });
        }

        cond_p.notify_one();
        return wrapper->get_future();
    }
private:
    std::vector<boost::thread> threads_p;
    boost::condition_variable cond_p;
    boost::mutex mutex_p;
    std::queue<Task> tasks_p;

    bool isStop = false;

    void start(std::size_t threads_count);
    void stop() noexcept; 
};
```

ThreadPool.cpp

```
#include "ThreadPool.h"

void ThreadPool::start(std::size_t threads_count)
{
    for (auto i = 0; i < threads_count; ++i)
    {
        threads_p.emplace_back([=] {
            while (true)
            {
                Task task;
                {
                    boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex>lock(mutex_p);

                    cond_p.wait(lock, [=] { return isStop || !tasks_p.empty();  });

                    if (isStop && tasks_p.empty())
                        break;

                    task = std::move(tasks_p.front()); // First task of the queue to execute 
                    tasks_p.pop();                     // Delete this task
                }

                task();
            }
        });
    }
}

void ThreadPool::stop() noexcept
{
    {
        boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(mutex_p);
        isStop = true;
    }
    cond_p.notify_all();

    for (auto& thread : threads_p)
    {
        thread.join();
    }
}

ThreadPool::ThreadPool(std::size_t threads_count)
{
    start(threads_count);
}

ThreadPool::~ThreadPool()
{
    stop();
}
```

And this is my counter class. I am filling vector with all names of .txt files.

Counter.cpp

```
#include "Counter.h"


Counter::Counter()
{
    std::cout << "Error" << "\n";
}

Counter::Counter(std::string& dirname_)
{
    dir = dirname_;
    // Does exist this folder?
    if (bfs::exists(dir) && bfs::is_directory(dir))
    {
        std::cout << "Dir is exist!\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Error: Dir is not exist\n";
    }
}

void Counter::allTxtFiles()
{
    for (auto& p : bfs::directory_iterator(dir))
    {
        if (p.path().extension() == ".txt")
            txt_files.push_back(p.path().string());
    }
}

// Count all words in file
void Counter::countAlg(std::ifstream& filename)
{
    std::string buffer;
    while (filename >> buffer)
    {
        ++words_count;
    }
}

uint Counter::getCount()
{
    return words_count;
}
```

I needs to iterate this vector in given number of threads and count words in each file. The ThreadsPool code is not very clear to me, so I do not know how to call it in the main function. What I should pass in enqueue function?

(Sorry for my English)

Comment: Buy **C++ Concurrency in Action** book by Anthony D. Williams if you are serious about multithreading. Improper multithreading might cause all sort of problem so it is a part of C++ where learning is important as debugging problems that are time dependant might be very hard.

Comment: @Phil1970 After this task, I will begin to read this book. I have a limited time for this task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument to `enqueue` is passed to the constructor of `std::packaged_task`, which has the following description:

> The class template std::packaged_task wraps any Callable target (function, lambda expression, bind expression, or another function object) so that it can be invoked asynchronously.

Since you already have a Counter class, you could create one task per file as follows in the `allTxtFiles` method:

```
void Counter::allTxtFiles() {
    for (auto& p : bfs::directory_iterator(dir)) {
        if (p.path().extension() == ".txt") {
            auto fut = theThreadPool.enqueue([path = p.path()]() {
                bfs::ifstream ifs(path);
                Counter c;
                c.countAlg(ifs);
                return c.getCount();
            });
            txt_files[p.path] = fut;
        }
    }
}
```

This will populate a `std::map<bfs::path, std::future<int> txt_files`, which you can then walk. You could also populate a `std::vector<std::pair<bfs::path, std::future<int>>` if you do not care about quickly mapping paths to word counts.